# Representing Rooted Tree in terms of class

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I am facing difficulty in understanding the following paragraph taken from [Representing Rooted Trees](http://www.brilliantsheep.com/lecture-notes-trees-and-traversal-uc-berkeley-cs-61b/). It basically shows two methods for representing trees. G & T is somewhat clear to me, but the other one is not that much clear to me, which shows class definition.

- G&T Option: Each node has 3-references: item, parent, children. The single reference for children has to refer to a list (so the node can have as many children as necessary).
- Another option is to have siblings linked directly. E.g.

  ```
  class SibTreeNode {
   Object item;
   SibTreeNode parent;
   SibTreeNode firstChild; // Left-most child.
   SibTreeNode nextSibling;
  }

  public class SibTree {
    SibTreeNode root;
    int size; // Number of nodes in the tree.
  }
  ```

The author in the video also claims  (at around 18 minutes) that  second method will require less memory. Can someone help me understand the class definitions and how this will require less memory  as compared to first method?

Comment: Let's construct a `SibTreeNode`. Okay, we have to construct `parent` and both children. To construct `parent`, we have to construct `SibTreeNode`... back to the beggining. Pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The second option is simply an intrusive singly-linked list. Intrusive singly-linked lists take up less memory because you don't need a pointer from the list node to the node's contents.

Look at the layout for the G&T option with an external list:

```
class ListNode {
    SibTreeNode* object;
    ListNode* nextElement;
};

class SibTreeNode {
    Object* item;
    SibTreeNode* parent;
    ListNode* childList;
};
```

with 5 pointers per SibTreeNode element instead of 4.

Comment: @Cicada: Are you referring to cache effects? If yes, keep in mind that you might want to access the payload during traversal, which drives up the cost for spatially separated list node and payload.